# Convert Sql to ES query

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I want to get All the records that has latest "created_on" time from elastic search documents.

In sql what i need is

`select * from table1 
where created_on = (select max(created_on) from table1)`

But i'm new to ES and don't know how to do it.

I Can first get the Max(created_on) date from ES and query again to get all the records that has Max(created_on).

Is there a way to get this with single query?

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
  "filter" : {
    "match_all" : { }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "created_on": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1
}
```

You can try this query and let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But it return one records when it has more than one.                       ```{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "created_on": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}```

Comment: Change the size as per your need. Change it to 999

Comment: then that will load all the first 999 records and i can't get all the records that has latest(created_on) only.   ```select * from table1 
where created_on = (select max(created_on) from table1)```

Comment: Just remove size field from the query you will get the entire record

Comment: No, Then that will return first 10 records (default) and that is not the all the records with the max(created_on)

Comment: You can fetch upto 10000 records at once. If you have more than 10000 records then es.scroll function allows you to get results past 10 000

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
// descending order  

var  entity= ctx.Table1.OrderByDescending(s => s.Created_on).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Currently i'm using ```{ "size": 1, "query": { "bool": { "filter": { "match_all": {} } } }, "sort": [ { "created_on": { "order": "desc" } } ] }``` to get the records. but from that i'm only able to get one records and not all the records that that has max(date).Could you please tell me where i need to include this variable. Sorry..I'm very new to ES.